# How to change the format of a column in GridView from c#

Tags: c#, datetime, gridview, format

I have a GridView and I want to export it to Word. I want to change the format of one column to datetime format ("dd.MM.yyyy")

```
var grid = new GridView { DataSource = dt};
grid.DataBind();
```

In *.aspx page this is very easy, it looks like in the example below:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="My_Date_Column"
                dataformatstring="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}"
                htmlencode="false" />
```

I want change format from c#, how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to alter the format of a column of a GridView from CodeBehind 
Add a `RowDataBound` to your grid view.

Then in the `GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)` method, you'll be able to access `e` which will provide you with access to the individual cells of that row where you can specify a formatter.

Here's an example of using the `RowDataBound` event
http://forums.asp.net/p/1589807/4025153.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", myDateTimeInstance);
```

Comment: that's the easy bit. how would he get access to that datetime from the code behind if its bound in the grid.

Comment: @EoinCampbell: Cast grid source as Datatable. and use like `dt[0]["columnname"].ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");`

Answer (score 0):

I think the format of column is based in system current date time format.

But when converting to string you can do so

```
String str = dt[RowNumber][ColumnName].ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
String formated = dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

OR

```
String formated = String.Format("{0:dd.MM.yyyy}", dt );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string formated = dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Possible formats are shown in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to format the entire column then it would be better if you can set the property for your concerned column

`gridview1.Columns[columnIndex].DataFormatString ="{0:dd.MM.yyyy}";`

I think you will need to cast the column as `BoundField` to access the property.

Comment: do you mind to check my thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157400/how-to-set-formatting-date-time-on-repositoryitem-combobox