# how to set formatting date time on repositoryitem combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, date, gridview, format

how do i get the format time in my gridview column to set it on my repository ?
the date in database was using `date time` which return an output of `8/1/2016 12:00:00 AM`
and i set in a gridcolumn with this method

```
    private void arrange()
    {

        gridView1.Columns["date"].VisibleIndex = 1;
        gridView1.Columns["date"].DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;
        gridView1.Columns["date"].DisplayFormat.FormatString = "dd MMM yyyy";
        gridView1.Columns["date"].format.FormatString = "dd MMM yyyy";

        gridView1.Columns["date"].Width = 150;
    }
```

the display on the gridcolumn of date is

[image]

the problem is when i using repository item on filter row it still getting the date format from database which is `8/1/2016 12:00:00 AM`. the image was like this

[image]

the code to add item into repository combobox was

```
    RepositoryItemComboBox repositoryItemComboBox2 = new RepositoryItemComboBox();

    private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.RowCount; i++)
        {
            if (gridView1.GetDataRow(i) == null)
            {
                break;
            }
        string txt = gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"].ToString();
        if (!repositoryItemComboBox2.Items.Contains(txt))
            {                    
                repositoryItemComboBox2.Items.Add(txt);
            }
        }

        if (e.Column.FieldName == "date" && view.IsFilterRow(e.RowHandle))
            { e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox2;

            repositoryItemComboBox2.Sorted = true;

            }
     }
```

iam thinking , how to resolve this is:

1. how to i really converting the column of date, not by display text
2. formating the column of date
3. formating the repository itemcombobox
4. using the original format, but on repository itembox change the display text same as how i did on column date
5. your suggestion

n.b: iam using devexpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
string txt = gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"].ToString();
```

To

```
string txt = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"].ToString()).Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

My tested code...

```
List<String> str = new List<String>();
str.Add("2016-08-01 12:00:00 AM");
str.Add("2016-08-02 12:00:00 AM");
str.Add("2016-08-03 12:00:00 AM");
str.Add("2016-08-04 12:00:00 AM");
str.Add("2016-08-05 12:00:00 AM");
str.Add("2016-08-06 12:00:00 AM");
str.Add("2016-08-07 12:00:00 AM");
str.Add("2016-08-08 12:00:00 AM");
str.Add("2016-08-09 12:00:00 AM");


foreach (var item in str)
{
  repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(item).Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"));
}
```

[image]

Comment: i have tested your code, and it works. because the row["date"] is not a time format but a string. so i can filter it. you should try the row["date"] change to a date time format first, like `DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Date"] = "26 Aug 2016";
            DateTime s = Convert.ToDateTime(row["date"]);
            var x = s.ToString("d");
            dt.Rows.Add(x);`
it wont get filter. can you try it by formatting the data in `row[date]` first. and then use your remaining code ?

Comment: I changed column type to DateTime. Still work. I added new photo to this solution. Check it!

Comment: but that's a search panel. can u modified a sample i sent to you? but dont modified the dt. because assuming it was from a database. by showing me `show auto filter row` and choose the date

Comment: I added two more photos. I copied your code and paste to mine. Still work :( @DavidChopperField

Comment: what happen after you click the dropdown list if `06 august 2016` ?
did it got filter or is it just a display text which cant filter the row format date?

Comment: when i clicked it or hit Enter. I became selected item.  For me, it works perfect. I think you should open another Question in StackOverFlow. You can get solution from others.

Comment: o.0 should ask with the same question ?
i dont know why mine cant get selected. can post the selected pic ?

Comment: added. As you wish :D. Haha

Comment: i see now, u change it from the cell.
can you add the event of the most bottom of my code?
it call custom row cell edit ? after u add it, right click on the header then choose the auto filter row, then drop down the list

Comment: Done. Check! No special. All works! I deleted recent photos. Long discussion LOL

Comment: Filter work perfect but it will not changed to selected value. It is filter in grid brother, it is not concern with repository. so selected value will not change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121901/discussion-between-david-chopperfield-and-triple-k).

Answer (score 0):

Change Display Format and Edit Format of repositoryItem

```
 repositoryItemComboBox1.DisplayFormat.FormatString = "dd MMM yyyy";
 repositoryItemComboBox1.DisplayFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;
 repositoryItemComboBox1.EditFormat.FormatString = "dd MM yyyy";
 repositoryItemComboBox1.EditFormat.FormatType = DevExpress.Utils.FormatType.DateTime;
```

Comment: whre do i put it ? because iam already try it. the result was the data when i drop down still `8/1/2016 12:00:00 AM` but after i select it, the format change to `dd MMM yyyy`.. the data on the drop down still using the database format

Comment: Yeah i tested and it is not working. I added new solution for you. Hope it works

Comment: yep, not working.. that's why iam thinking how about convert the column date format instead of `display text`

Comment: I have updated my new solution with sample code. @DavidChopperField

Comment: i havent test it, but iam once also using `DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"]);
                var xx = date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");` and store the repository item with xx, but when i dropdown and filter it didnt find it because the format between gridview and dropdown was different.

Comment: filter also work. I capture it and added picture in my solution. Check it! @DavidChopperField

Comment: can u post more data , and after filter it ?
is it because the `list` if so, maybe i should loop the `list` instead of manually type it?

Comment: or maybe can you send me your sample, so i can try to edit as i want  ?

Comment: Can i share you via DropBox? @DavidChopperField

Comment: could you send me yours ? it seems a bit confuse because before you convert the `string txt` and in the bottom to add the items you adding by `item` variable.. and str list is it from gridview ?

Comment: anythings fine, just put a link maybe ? thanks very much before, i hope thats what i want, also i need to implement your to mine. so i probably cant use all your code.(if you are worried)

Comment: Download it. Don't forget to accept as solution :D https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90912056/Sample.rar @DavidChopperField

Comment: i cant run your program. do you another approach ? like formatting the column date format ? because when i see your code  `repositoryItemComboBox1.Items.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(item).Date.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"));` its only convert just in the combobox, but the gridview format is different, which result cant filter it

Comment: why can't you run? VS 2012 version, is it higher than yours? Can't you use filter in Grid or in Repository ComboBox? I can Find in grid and also in comboBox. Both works

Comment: iam using vs 2015, i copied all you code and make a sample of it, do you mind check it? can filter by show filter auto row https://www.dropbox.com/s/tqr09mbip8zr2xv/WindowsFormsApplication1.rar?dl=0

Comment: I can't open VS 2015 solution. Sorry!

Comment: okay, maybe just copy paste my a bit of code to yours ? only the convert date. and also i try your newest code from newest picture i cant filter it.. @@ on the your picture you only show it by search panel not auto filter row.. pls

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121893/discussion-between-david-chopperfield-and-triple-k).

Comment: Download it. It has pictures to prove it.
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/90912056/GridFilter.rar

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error  'Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.XtraEditors.v14.1, Version=14.1.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b88d1754d700e49a' or one of its dependencies. Invalid pointer (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004003 (E_POINTER))' Sample C:\Users\dpramono\Downloads\GridFilter\GridFilter\Sample\Sample\LC

Comment: Maybe Devexpress version different.Mine v14. Replace my Form1.cs to your sample project and test it.

Comment: i think we are really miscommunication.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/oyuf3nd909s3ynk/WindowsFormsApplication2.rar?dl=0 
it wont get filter, pls check the note
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bf9wigi5x2o948/3.txt?dl=0

Comment: Maybe you should use same dateTime format for both grid and repository. If it is not important, don't waste your time in that. Change it.

Comment: yep , that's i know. if we got same format it should get filtered, but the thing is the gridcolumn iam using format from database which is date time returning value of `8/1/2016 12:00:00 AM` thats why need filtered with different format... or what i think was how do i re-convert the format of all value on column[date]. you should see my other thinking to solve this...may be u got an idea?

Comment: Like i did, change both to 08/01/2016 (dd/MM/yyyy) format. My sample has already show you a way if you use same format.

Comment: how do i change my default time format from database ? to format `dd MMM yyyy` when i select the query and call it, the format was `date time 8/1/2016 12:00:00 AM`

Comment: Only way is to use ToString("dd MMM yyyy") or use default DateTime.ToLongDateString() , something like that. Can't you change your UI datetime to DB datetime format? It will be easier