# How can I compare a Date to a DateTime in VB.NET?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, datetime

I just need to compare a date entered by a user to a `DateTime` stored in my database. I have tried converting the `DateTime` to `Date` like this:

```
select CONVERT(date, startdate) from myTable
```

However, when the information is shown in my `GridView`, there is still a time attached to the date. (The time shown is 12:00:00.) What can I do to either convert the `DateTime` to just a `Date` when the information is pulled from the database, or compare a `Date` to a `DateTime`? Why is there still a time shown, even though I converted the `DateTime` to `Date`?

**Update

It may be worth noting that I can run the query that populates my `GridView` in SQL Server Management Studio and the results shown are what I expect-- no time is in the date. I think the problem must be in VB.NET...

**More information

I am having the user fill out a form that will be used to search the database for relevant results. However, as it stands, no results are being returned because the user enters a normal date in the `Date` field on the form, while the field in the database is a `DateTime`. This is why I need to know how to convert it.

**Requested Information

Here is the query I'm using:

```
select convert(date, startdate) as startdate, CONVERT(date, completedate) as completedate
from myTable
```

Here is the result set in SQL Server Management Studio (no times):

[image]

Here is the result set in the grid (shows times):

[image]

I obviously omitted information from the database, but the information shown is all I'm worried about. I had to omit confidential information.

Comment: Would it be sufficient to adjust the rendered appearance of the date? [How to change the format of a column in GridView from c#](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10681378/1115360)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have updated the question.

Comment: So, to be clear, the `Date` comes back from the database without a time, yet the grid is populated *with* the time, correct? You want to know how to remove the time?

Comment: @ragerory That is correct. I need the search to return results based on just the date, not the time.

Comment: The .net framework doesn't have just an intrinsic date type. The `Date` type in VB is syntactically the same as the `system.datetime` type (similar to how `Integer` is the same as `system.int32`).

Comment: Please show us a small sample of data from the database and the query you are using.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I have updated the question.

Comment: This is a presentation layer format issue and nothing to do with your database. Using gridview you can specify a format string  for the date. You could use a format string like 'yyyy-MM-dd'  which would then not display the time portion. Something like `DataFormatString="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"`. If you want more a more specific pointer please post your grid code where you bind the date column.

Comment: @ic3man7019 I was hoping that you would show the query used to select a particular date based on the user input - could you show that to us please? And the VB code that you use to create the query. That seems to be where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It returns it as a DateTime in .NET which automatically adds the time. Just do the conversion in VB.NET when you do your display. For instance if you're using MVC and you're passing up your viewmodel, in your Razor syntax you'd do `vm.DateRetrieved.ToString("d")`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx

```
Dim dateTimeStamp = DateTime.Now  
Console.WriteLine(dateTimeStamp.ToString("d")) 

'12/6/2016 14:22:28PM
'12/6/2016
```